# Ubuntu 13.10 Nautilus not showing image previews

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10, nautilus

How to enable image-previews on Nautilus on a network folder?

Comment: thanks for voting down without any comment ..

Comment: possibly helpful http://askubuntu.com/questions/211843/why-i-cant-see-the-thumbnails-in-nautilus and http://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bnautilus%5D+preview

Comment: didn't know about askubuntu-stackoverflow. thx.